# How do I count the values in a column by each month?

Tags: sql, dataframe

In my data frame, I am trying to count number of values of a column per month, given by the time column in SQL. I want the output to have a count of the number of values in a column for each month. I know I can use the where function to count for one month and I could do this for all 12 months, but was wondering if there was a more efficient way.
Here's the inefficient example:

```
SELECT
    count(column1) AS Total
FROM DataFrame
WHERE MONTH(date) == 1
 GROUP by column1 ORDER by count(column1) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Remove `where`. Add 12 columns like `count(case when month(date) = 1 then 1 end) as January` Be careful when results span more than a single year. Also search for "conditional aggregation" and "pivot table" for more info.

Comment: It's not clear whether you want the output in 12 rows or in 12 columns. We don't appear to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @shawnt00 sorry your answer was correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to count distinct values of a column per month, given by the time column in SQL. I

You seem to want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as mon, approx_count_distinct(column1, 0.1) AS Total
FROM DataFrame
GROUP by MONTH(date)
ORDER by Total DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that using `MONTH()` without `YEAR()` or a filter on the date is highly suspicious.

Comment: I want to group by the values in column1 though

Comment: @GraceSullivan . . . That makes no sense.  `approx_count_distinct()` is an aggregation function -- at least in any database I know that has that function.  Aggregating by aggregation functions is, shall I say, unusual.  And your question is really answered by the query here.

Comment: Sorry! I meant it to just be a count not a distinct count. So for example, I would like to know if x is in column1 5 times in January, 0 times in February, etc. and then y is in column1 2 times in January, etc.